# To be +gerund with agent

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is it correct to say?

> It was me working on my car that was causing annoying sounds.

Me working on my car – gerund (with agent) as subject complement.

That was causing annoying sounds – relative clause which modifies "it", which is the subject of our sentence.

Comment: The subject is the dummy pronoun "it". The relative clause in an _it_ cleft is not a modifier.  Thus the words "me working on my car" and "that was causing annoying sounds" do not form a syntactic constituent.

Comment: The main problem is the wording: it is unclear whether it is (i) your working or (ii) your car that was causing annoying sounds

Comment: If I delete "on my car " is it correct to use _to be+ agent+gerund

Comment: Yes: the antecedent for the relative clause would then be just the gerund-participial clause "me working".

Answer (score 2):

> *It was me working on my car that was causing annoying sounds.*

The subject is the dummy pronoun "it".

The relative clause in an *it*-cleft construction is not a modifier. Thus it does not combine with its antecedent, in this case *me working on my car*, to form a syntactic constituent. Rather, the relative clause appears in extranuclear position at the end.

Comment: Can we use   To be+ agent + gerund
For example
Idk like describing a photo
This  is me and my friend holding the camera

Comment: @DARKDRAGON Yes, but unlike your original example, this is not an _it-_ cleft construction.

Comment: thanks ı just wondered if we could use to be+agent+gerund. (For ex. What I saw was him working on his car.) because my teacher said : to be +agent+gerund was wrong ,and I said how about meme lines on Reddit like "me watching TV" .that structure must be correct.anyway thanks to you I know we can use to be +gerund with agent

Comment: @DARKDRAGON Yes: _What I saw was him working on his car_ is fine.

Comment: Please forgive me for taking your time but there something that got me thinking for a while ,and I am so curious to get the right answer. For exemple
I saw him walking while holding  a book
While holding can belong to either Me or him ,right?
(In this case , probably him)

Comment: It'a ambiguous. It could be him or me that is holding a book. To make the meaning clear, it would be better to say _I saw him walking while he was holding a book_ or  _I saw him walking while I was holding a book_.

Comment: Thanks a lot .you have been a lot of help for me thank again